Python3 Getting SIGSEGV error from PyQt6 QPixmap
I am using PyQt6 to create a GUI to read data from a sensor. I am using a Subject-Observer pattern to call an update function. The code for this pattern is below
#Subject Base class
class Subject():
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []
    
    def __del__(self):
        pass
    
    def attach(self, observer):
        if (observer not in self.observers):
            self.observers.append(observer)
            return True
        
        return False
    
    def remove(self, observer):
        if (observer in self.observers):
            self.observers.remove(observer)
            return True
        
        return False
    
    def notify(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            for observer in self.observers:
                observer.update(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return True
            
        except:
            return False

#Observer base class
class Observer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def update(self, observable, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

In this update function a numpy array is retrieved and resized using cv2.resize() and converted to a QImage. This QImage is turned into a Pixmap to render to the screen, a trimmed version of my code is shown below
#Import ZED module
import pyzed.sl as sl

#Import system modules
import datetime
import math

import cv2

#Import PyQt6 modules
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QSize
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, QWidget


#Import project modules
import Communication
import ZEDController as ZEDController
import DataFormatter

class GUIInterface(QWidget, Communication.Observer):
    def __init__(self, window_width, window_height, parent = None):
        #Run parent class constructors
        super().__init__(parent)

        #Scale to reduce native images by
        self.image_scale = 2.0
        resized_width = 1280/self.image_scale
        resized_height = 720/self.image_scale
        self.resized_tuple = (int(resized_width), int(resized_height))

...

        #Create labels for displaying images and other visualizations
        self.window_display = QLabel()

...

def update(self, observable, *args, **kwargs):
        #If object calling update() is ZEDController
        if (isinstance(observable, ZEDController.ZEDController)):
            if self.camera_info is None:
                self.camera_info = observable.camera_info

            if (self.showF == True):
                frame_np = cv2.resize(observable.frame.get_data(), self.resized_tuple)
                if (self.window_display is not None):
                    image = QImage(frame_np.data, frame_np.shape[1], frame_np.shape[0], QImage.Format.Format_RGBA8888).rgbSwapped()
                    self.window_display.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

            elif (self.showD == True):
                depth_frame_viewable_np = cv2.resize(observable.depth_frame_viewable.get_data(), self.resized_tuple) #Note its still actually a 4-channel matrix even though ZED says otherwise on the website 

                if (self.window_display is not None):
                    depth_image = QImage(depth_frame_viewable_np.data, depth_frame_viewable_np.shape[1], depth_frame_viewable_np.shape[0], QImage.Format.Format_RGBA8888).rgbSwapped()
                    self.window_display.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(depth_image))



The code works normally for a while, and the image conversion works, but then the error suddenly occurs. The offending code seems to be in the conversion from QImage to QPixmap. I ran the code in gdb with the following main.py file
#
import GUIInterface

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

import sys

#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUIInterface.GUIInterface(1280, 720)
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I noticed during the gdb debugging it took a lot longer for the error to occur, but eventually this happened.
[New Thread 0xffffa1fbf120 (LWP 49170)]
[New Thread 0xffffa27cf120 (LWP 49171)]
[New Thread 0xffffa2fdf120 (LWP 49172)]

Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000ffffcf169e5c in QPixmap::devicePixelRatio() const () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Gui.so.6
(gdb) backtrace'
Unmatched single quote.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000ffffcf169e5c in QPixmap::devicePixelRatio() const () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Gui.so.6
#1  0x0000ffffce06d008 in QStyle::drawItemPixmap(QPainter*, QRect const&, int, QPixmap const&) const () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6
#2  0x0000ffffce13d298 in QLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6
#3  0x0000ffffce83d920 in sipQLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) () at /home/robert/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/QtWidgets.abi3.so
#4  0x0000ffffce02bc28 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6
#5  0x0000ffffce0b5280 in QFrame::event(QEvent*) () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6
#6  0x0000ffffce83f834 in sipQLabel::event(QEvent*) () at /home/robert/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/QtWidgets.abi3.so
#7  0x0000ffffcdfd54c0 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6
#8  0x0000ffffce96a14c in sipQApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /home/robert/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/QtWidgets.abi3.so
#9  0x0000ffffcff94a90 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6
#10 0x0000ffffce023a54 in QWidgetPrivate::sendPaintEvent(QRegion const&) () at /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt6Widgets.so.6
#11 0x0000ffffce023f8c in QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice*, QRegion const&, QPoint const&, QFlags<QWidgetPrivate::DrawWidgetFlag>, QPainter*, QWidgetRepaintManager*) ()

The backtrace seems to indicate that the issue is caused by QPixmap, any suggestions on how I could fix this?
Thanks In Advance

What is Communication.Observer? And what calls update() (which, by the way, is an existing function of all QWidgets and should not be overwritten)? Please clarify your question with a more detailed context, and provide a proper [mre].
